# my first else condition jumps to the second else

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i am trying to NOT let the first ELSE proceed until it meets the condition to require an input that will include only 1 or 2 or 3... but it failes to do so... after 1 time print it goes on to the second ELSE... what am i doing wrong here ?

```
def line_func(): # line to separate
print("==========================================================================") 

def vs1():
print("") # vertical space

def start1():
vs1()
print("=====================================================")
print("Would you like to start? Choose with (y)yes or (n)no.\n=====================================================\n")   
while True:
    start = input("Answer: ")
    vs1()
    if start == "y" or start == "Y" or start == "yes" or start == "YES" or start == "Yes":         
        line_func()
        vs1()

        menu1 = input("How would you like to proceed?\n\n1)Find an enemy to crush\n2)Restart game\n3)Exit game\n\nodgovor: ")
        if menu1 == "1":
            vs1()
            start_round()
        elif menu1 == "2":
            vs1()
            print("================= RESTARTING GAME ===================")
            vs1()
            print("=====================================================")
            print("Would you like to start? Choose with (y)yes or (n)no.\n=====================================================\n")
            continue
            start1()             
        elif menu1 == "3":
            print("Ok see you next time... bye bye :)")       
            break
        else:
            print("You have to choose one of the options to proceed...")

    elif start == "n" or start == "N" or start == "no" or start == "NO" or start == "No":
        print("Ok see you next time... bye bye :)")       
        break
    else:
        print("You have to choose with yes or no...")

start1()
```

Comment: Just a tip: when you change the input to `start = input("Answer: ").lower()`, you can reduce your first if to `if start == "y" or start == "yes"` and also to elif about the `no`-Option

Answer (score 0):

try the below code, working for me:

```
def line_func(): # line to separate
    print("==========================================================================") 

def vs1():
    print("") # vertical space

def start1():
    vs1()
    print("=====================================================")
    print("Would you like to start? Choose with (y)yes or (n)no.\n=====================================================\n")   
while not start:
    start = input("Answer: ")
    vs1()
    if start == "y" or start == "Y" or start == "yes" or start == "YES" or start == "Yes":
        start = True
        line_func()
        vs1()

        menu1 = input("How would you like to proceed?\n\n1)Find an enemy to crush\n2)Restart game\n3)Exit game\n\nodgovor: ")
        if menu1 == "1":
            vs1()
            start_round()
        elif menu1 == "2":
            vs1()
            print("================= RESTARTING GAME ===================")
            vs1()
            print("=====================================================")
            print("Would you like to start? Choose with (y)yes or (n)no.\n=====================================================\n")
            continue
            start1()             
        elif menu1 == "3":
            print("Ok see you next time... bye bye :)")       
            break
        else:
            print("You have to choose one of the options to proceed...")

    elif start == "n" or start == "N" or start == "no" or start == "NO" or start == "No":
        start = True
        print("Ok see you next time... bye bye :)")       
        break
    else:
        print("You have to choose with yes or no...")
        start = False

start1()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
     line_func()
    vs1()

    menu1 = input("How would you like to proceed?\n\n1)Find an enemy to crush\n2)Restart game\n3)Exit game\n\nodgovor: ")
    if menu1 == "1":
        vs1()
        start_round()
    elif menu1 == "2":
        vs1()
        print("================= RESTARTING GAME ===================")
        vs1()
        print("=====================================================")
        print("Would you like to start? Choose with (y)yes or (n)no.\n=====================================================\n")
        continue
        start1()             
    elif menu1 == "3":
        print("Ok see you next time... bye bye :)")       
        break
    else:
        print("You have to choose one of the options to proceed...")
```

What you need  is another `while` loop.The break condition is up to your demand.